# Using FFMPEG Android Library to convert PCM to m4a

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I am using https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java.

I have a PCM file that I created using AudioRecord.

I am now trying to convert the PCM file to an m4a file.

Running the following command converts it but it speeds up the audio making the voices on the recording sound like the chipmunks.

Finished command : ffmpeg -f s16be -i /storage/emulated/0/GMT/recordTestNew.pcm -strict -2  -y -c:a aac -b:a 176k /storage/emulated/0/GMT/recordTestFFMPEG.m4a

Which gives

```
SUCCESS with output : WARNING: linker: /data/user/0/com.globalmedicaltranscriptionapp/files/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
                                                                            ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
                                                                              built on Oct  7 2014 15:08:46 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                                                                              configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
                                                                              libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
                                                                              libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
                                                                              libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
                                                                              libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
                                                                              libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
                                                                              libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
                                                                              libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
                                                                              libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
                                                                            [s16be @ 0xf72ba000] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
                                                                            Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : mono
                                                                            Input #0, s16be, from '/storage/emulated/0/GMT/recordTestNew.pcm':
                                                                              Duration: 00:00:02.70, bitrate: 705 kb/s
                                                                                Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16be, 44100 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 705 kb/s
                                                                            Output #0, ipod, to '/storage/emulated/0/GMT/recordTestFFMPEG.m4a':
                                                                              Metadata:
                                                                                encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
                                                                                Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 128 kb/s
                                                                                Metadata:
                                                                                  encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 aac
                                                                            Stream mapping:
                                                                              Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16be (native) -> aac (native))
                                                                            Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
                                                                            size=      30kB time=00:00:01.90 bitrate= 130.0kbits/s    
                                                                            size=      44kB time=00:00:02.71 bitrate= 131.8kbits/s    
                                                                            video:0kB audio:43kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.801121%
```

The audio clip should actually be about 11 seconds long. The frequency should be 11025, The encoding is using Android's AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, the channels are using AndioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_DEFAULT.

This is my first time working with audio so it's been a struggle. The reason why I am using AudioRecord is because I need the audio files to be in a form that allows me to split them and potentially add new audio clips in the middle.

It seems like an issue due to the frequency not being passed to the output. I tried updating the above command to

Finished command : ffmpeg -f s16be -ar 11025 -i /storage/emulated/0/GMT/recordTestNew.pcm -strict -2  -y -c:a aac /storage/emulated/0/GMT/recordTestFFMPEG.m4a

Which gives

```
FAILED with output : WARNING: linker: /data/user/0/com.globalmedicaltranscriptionapp/files/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
                                                                            ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
                                                                              built on Oct  7 2014 15:08:46 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
                                                                              configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-cflags='-I/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/sb/Source-Code/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
                                                                              libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
                                                                              libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
                                                                              libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
                                                                              libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
                                                                              libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
                                                                              libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
                                                                              libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
                                                                              libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
                                                                            [s16be @ 0xf707a000] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
                                                                            Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : mono
                                                                            Input #0, s16be, from '/storage/emulated/0/GMT/recordTestNew.pcm':
                                                                              Duration: 00:00:10.81, bitrate: 176 kb/s
                                                                                Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16be, 11025 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 176 kb/s
                                                                            [aac @ 0xf7043c00] Too many bits per frame requested
                                                                            Output #0, ipod, to '/storage/emulated/0/GMT/recordTestFFMPEG.m4a':
                                                                                Stream #0:0: Audio: aac, 0 channels, 128 kb/s
                                                                                Metadata:
                                                                                  encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 aac
                                                                            Stream mapping:
                                                                              Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16be (native) -> aac (native))
                                                                            Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

04-11 14:22:23.029 11026-11026/com.globalmedicaltranscriptionapp D/AudioPlayer: Finished command : ffmpeg -f s16be -ar 11025 -i /storage/emulated/0/GMT/recordTestNew.pcm -strict -2  -y -c:a aac /storage/emulated/0/GMT/recordTestFFMPEG.m4a

Doing that makes the input seem to have the correct duration and bit rate but then I get the following error.

```
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16be (native) -> aac (native))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

I have tried a million other configurations but still can't get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the full console readout of the command.

Comment: Updated it with the full console readouts and a little more information.

Comment: Why do so many ffmpeg + Android questions specifically involve ancient ffmpeg 2.4.2?

Comment: It must be due to libraries like I posted being outdated and that most of the tutorials I came across for implementing FFMPEG in Android projects are a few years old. Thanks for your help LordNeckbeard, the duplicate post you linked to, answered my question. I had been to that post before but just didn't understand it completely.

Comment: Since I could not update FFMPEG which would have been the ideal choice, I updated the command to "ffmpeg -f s16be -ar 11025 -i /storage/emulated/0/GMT/recordTestNew.pcm -strict -2 -y -c:a aac -b:a 64k /storage/emulated/0/GMT/recordTestFFMPEG.m4a" which worked. I needed to set the bitrate to a smaller number.